# i am trying to create tables but it show me 2 errors, how i fix it?

Tags: sql

2 errors were found during analysis.

> Unexpected beginning of statement. (near "admin_id" at position 349) 
>   Unrecognized statement type. (near "INT" at position 358)

```
CREATE TABLE Users (
  user_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  email VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL,
  password CHAR(41) NOT NULL,
  name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  phone VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  gender VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL,
  fbinfo  VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  age INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (user_id),
  UNIQUE INDEX (email)
)

CREATE TABLE Admin (
  admin_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  email VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL,
  password CHAR(41) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (admin_id),
  UNIQUE INDEX (email)
) 

CREATE TABLE Task (
  task_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  tex VARCHAR(140) NOT NULL,
  datetime DATE,
  status INT,
  calendar BOOLEAN,
  PRIMARY KEY (task_id),
  lat DECIMAL(9,6),
  long DECIMAL(9,6)
)
```

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. (Some product specific constructions there...)

Comment: You must mention your server but did you try with a ; at the end of each sentence?

Comment: If you are using Oracle, a statement terminator, usually `;`, needs to be used at the end of each CREATE TABLE statement.

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing this in one execution, you would need to include a `;` at the end of each of your table creation statements.

```
CREATE TABLE Users (
  user_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  email VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL,
  password CHAR(41) NOT NULL,
  name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  phone VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  gender VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL,
  fbinfo  VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  age INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (user_id),
  UNIQUE INDEX (email)
);

CREATE TABLE Admin (
  admin_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  email VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL,
  password CHAR(41) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (admin_id),
  UNIQUE INDEX (email)
);

CREATE TABLE Task (
  task_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  tex VARCHAR(140) NOT NULL,
  datetime DATE,
  status INT,
  calendar BOOLEAN,
  PRIMARY KEY (task_id),
  lat DECIMAL(9,6),
  long DECIMAL(9,6)
);
```